# Converting Json Object to String - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, object

Imagine I make an request to my api that return an `mysql_query("Select * from user where id=1")`.

After the request is done, it returns the user info in json.
I do some debuging, `NSlog(@"JSON : %@",json);` and it gives me this:

```
JSON : (
    {
    aboutme = "";
    active = 0;
    birthday = "1992-10-14";
    "city_id" = 0;
    email = "test@test.com";
    fbid = "";
    firstname = test;
    gender = 1;
    id = 162;
    lastname = test;
    password = "$2a$12$8iy.sGr.4V/Ea3GfHZe0m.SLDrvoSj3/wYRlWsNce1yyCMeCbDrMC";
    "phone_number" = "";
    "recovery_date" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    "register_date" = "2013-06-06 02:44:20";
    salt = "8iy.sGr.4V/Ea3GfHZe0m";
    "user_type_id" = 1;
    username = test;
}
)
```

Now I parse it with `AFJONDecode` and when I get the `[json valueForKey:@"username"];` and debug it ( `NSlog(@"username = %@",[json valueForKey@"username"]);` ) and I get this:

```
username = (
    testeteste739
)
```

It gives me an object ( because in the Json, the username = test and not username = "test").

So, how can i convert this object to string?

** UPDATE **

I resolve it by the following way:

```
NSArray *username = [JSON valueForKey:@"username"];
username = [username objectAtIndex:0];
```

Is there any better way to overpass this?
Thanks

Comment: The value of `username` is an `NSString` with a value of `@"test"`. Just because it doesn't log with quotes doesn't mean it isn't a string.

Comment: I don't think so, because if i do NSlog(@"username = --%@--", username) i get:
`username = --(
    testeteste1009
)--`

Comment: First off, what you have above is not a JSON string.  It is a dump of NSDictionary and NSArray objects, representing the interalized form of the JSON.  In other words, it is already "parsed".

Comment: What you have there is an NSArray (apparently named "json") which contains a single array element which is an NSDictionary.  To get, eg, username you'd first extract element zero of json (`NSDictionary* dict = [json objectAtIndex:0]`) and then extract the appropriate array element (`NSString* username = [dict objectForKey:@"username"];`).

Comment: And note that since the above is an Objective-C object dump, and not JSON, string values that have no blanks or special characters are shown without enclosing quotes.

Comment: (I don't know where you got "testeteste1009".  You should have gotten an error trying to perform objectForKey on "json", since "json" is an array.  Somehow you picked up some garbage.  And I suspect that you've got a kluge of statements you're not showing us that are creating a number of weird effects.)

Comment: (If you are in truth doing AFJSONDecode on the already-parsed JSON, I suppose that could produce some "interesting" results, though I'd think it would just throw an exception.)

Comment: All i wanted was to get the value "username". I already resolve it, so thanks everyone and sorry for all my confusion!

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida did you find better way to do it like
NSArray *username = [JSON valueForKey:@"username"];
username = [username objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As JSON is a dictionary object, so you can get your json data to JSONDic NSDictionary variable and parse it to string as follows:-

```
NSDictionary *JSONDic=[[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:JSONDic
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted 
                                                     error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: That is, of course, the way to create a JSON string, given an internal representation in NSArray/NSDictionary objects.  (Hopefully your JSONDict object has contents when you actually do this.)  I think the OP is still struggling to get values OUT of the JSON.

Comment: As question title specifies the he want to convert JSON to string I did this , he didn't specify in the title that he want values out of JSON.

Comment: He doesn't know what he wants.

Comment: All i wanted was to get the value "username". I already resolve it, so thanks everyone and sorry for all my confusion!